# Free software to turn on PC automatically

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-8

Am looking for a free software to turn on my Windows PC automatically after hibernation, sleep and shut down(if possible). It should provide option to assign time to turn on or wake up my PC. Is there such a free software ?

Comment: After shutdown, obviously there is no software running, but you could consider a plug/socket with a timer

Comment: Did you Google? Did you find http://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/  or http://www.pcworld.com/article/256309/tweeking_windows_7s_sleeping_habits.html or https://www.raymond.cc/blog/automatically-wake-up-from-windows-stand-by-and-hibernation/ ? the answers are easy enough to find. G.I.Y.F

Comment: Like @Mawg implied, you can't start a PC with software after a shutdown. The only thing that pops into my mind is [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), though it only works in a network and you need another PC to start the desired one.

Comment: I thought of that - but (how) will it work if the machine is powered off?

Comment: @Mawg I don't exactly know how it technically works. But as long as your machine has a power source it *does* work - we use it a lot at our company. But you need a motherboard/network card that supports WoL, so it won't work with any PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WakeUpOnStandby](http://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/) should be able to do this.

Note that I say "should" because while wake up from a sleep state works on basically any machine, waking up from hibernation must be supported by the BIOS, so it may fail if your PC doesn't support this. 
The program is free, so have a try and see for yourself if it works on your machine.